# Send Dictionary from swift to objective-c class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, nsdictionary

I am implemented CRToast in my swift project. CRToast is written in Objective-c. Now i want to call a method of CRToast from swift file for which i need to send a Dictionary as a parameter. Dictionary contains different types of values in it. How can i send it successfully.

```
func showToast(){

     let options: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [kCRToastTextKey: "Hello World!",           
        kCRToastTextAlignmentKey: NSTextAlignmet.Center,
        kCRToastBackgroundColorKey: UIColor.redColor(),
        kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
        kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
        kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey: CRToastAnimationDirection.Left,
        kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey: CRToastAnimationDirection.Right
]

    CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions(options, completionBlock: {() -> Void in
        NSLog("Completed")
    })
}
```

the same function when called in objective-c

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                      kCRToastTextKey : @"Hello World!",
                      kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                      kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                      kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                      kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                      kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionLeft),
                      kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionRight)
                      };
[CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:options
                        completionBlock:^{
                            NSLog(@"Completed");
                        }];
```

The method i need to call is ***showNotificationWithOptions***

```
+ (void)showNotificationWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options completionBlock:(void (^)(void))completion {
[self showNotificationWithOptions:options
                   apperanceBlock:nil
                  completionBlock:completion];
```

}

The error is always get is can't cast to expected type [NSObject : AnyObject]!. Can someone guide me how to send Dictionary with different values

Comment: The .Center doesn't look right. Shouldn't it be NSTextAlignment.Center or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass enum raw value:

```
func showToast(){

        let options: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [kCRToastTextKey: "Hello World!",
            kCRToastTextAlignmentKey: NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue,
            kCRToastBackgroundColorKey: UIColor.redColor(),
            kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
            kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
            kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey: CRToastAnimationDirection.Left.rawValue,
            kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey: CRToastAnimationDirection.Right.rawValue
        ]

        CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions(options, completionBlock: {() -> Void in
            NSLog("Completed")
        })
    }
```

Comment: Awesome man, u saved my day, can you also explain the logic behind rawValue enum. Upvoted u already

Comment: Unfortunately an enum is not transferrable to Swift from Objective-C, it needs to be an NS_ENUM. Thats why we use its raw value